# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_7: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras

I am new in Deep Learning, and I'm trying to create this simple RNN architecture in Keras using Google Colab:

1. Input layer of 12 input neurons
2. One Recurrent hidden layer of 1 chidden neuron for now
3. Output layer of 1 output neuron

Here is my code below:

```
train_x, valid_x = model_selection.train_test_split(df_tea,random_state=2, stratify=df_tea['offer_Offer'])

train_x.shape
=> (4982, 12)

valid_x.shape
=> (1661, 12)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(12))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(SimpleRNN(1 , input_shape=(128, 12)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_x.values, valid_x.values,
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=128,
                    validation_split=0.2)
```

Upon running model.compile, I got this error:

**ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_7: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2**

Please help me as I don't understand what this means. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7403